# UITableView swipe delete bottom line remove

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to remove bottom line. See below image

[image]

I have simple code for `swipe` delete and `UIView` in `uitableview`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, can you try to change cell's separator style to none?

Comment: @elia yes but bottom line still same. Even changing separator color still not change.

Comment: so for now, I recommend with a custom `Delete` like same as the current one and you can test out to compare the white line. It might be default.

Comment: and can you try if there's a border of orange view delete it?